# Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: codeigniter-4

Need help, I want to sum one column in codeigniter4 but I get this error:

> Error: object of class CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder could not be converted to string

This is my model:

```
public function tot_crew_wni_arr() {
    return $this->db->table('tbl_est_arr')->selectSum('crew_wni_arr');
}
```

at controller

```
$data = array(
'tot_crew_wni_arr' => $this->Model_home->tot_crew_wni_arr(),
);
return view('layout/v_wrapper', $data);
```

This is my view:

```
<h3><?= $tot_crew_wni_arr ?></h3>
```

Comment: You have to chain it to ->get() method to get the results. You can see the example on the following https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model function should look something like this:

```
public function tot_crew_wni_arr() {
    $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('tbl_est_arr');
    return $builder->selectSum('crew_wni_arr')->get();
}
```